# How to regex match individual html tag with inner tag when multiple tags exists in text

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code

let's say my text looks like this:

```
<button class="b1"
    (click)="b1()">
    <mat-icon>icon</mat-icon>
</button>

<button class="b1"
    (click)="b1()">
    <mat-icon>othericon</mat-icon>
    <span>Some Text</span>
</button>
```

I'm trying to use regex (Rust based without lookaround... because that's what VSCode uses) to select only buttons that include the span inside them. I've tried this:

`<button[\n\s\S]*?>[\n\s\S]*?span[\n\s\S]*?</button>`

... but the problem is that it matches from the start of the first button in the file even if it doesn't include a span. I thought the Lazy quantifier would find the shortest match, but it doesn't seem to work that way. See my RegExr http://regexr.com/4cdra for an example. I want it to match over multiple lines which is the reason for the `[\n\s\S]`.

`<button[\n\s\S]*?>[\n\s\S]*?</button>` ... doing this works well to match just the single tags... however getting it to work with inner tags is where I'm getting stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should avoid trying to parse HTML using regex.  Given that you are doing this from an IDE, you may not have any choice.  One trick which can work here is to use a tempered dot to avoid parsing a closing `</button>` tag:

```
<button[^>]*>((?!</button>)[\s\S])*<span>[\s\S]*?</button>
```

### Demo

Most of the pattern is probably familiar to you.  Of note, I use `[\s\S]` to match across newlines.  Also, consider the tempered dot trick:

```
((?!</button>)[\s\S])*
```

This uses a negative lookahead to match any character, one at a time, so long as the closing `</button>` tag is not encountered.  This prevents the pattern from crossing tags while trying to find a `<span>`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, unfortunately Rust regex doesn't support lookahead. However I think this maybe the only option to really do what I want. So I'll use a different ide to do what I need with what you've provided! Cheers Joel

Comment: @JoelDuckworth Glad to help you.  It sounds like Rust regex is a bit rusty, and the engine should probably be upgraded.